# Find the indices of the odd numbers in an integer vector

Tags: r, integer

Say we have some vector:

```
someVector = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 9, 2, -5, -2)
```

I want to get a vector that has the locations in `someVector` of all the odd elements

so in this case it would look like...

```
resultVector = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
> which(someVector %% 2 == 1)
[1] 1 2 5 6 8
```

Answer (score 7):

```
library(schoolmath)
which(is.odd(someVector))
[1] 1 2 5 6 8
```

just for fun here the code of the `is.odd` function :

```
function (x) 
{
  start <- 1
  end <- length(x) + 1
  while (start < end) {
    y <- x[start]
    if (y == 0) {
      cat("Please enter a number > 0")
      end
    }
    test1 <- y/2
    test2 <- floor(test1)
    if (test1 != test2) {
      if (start == 1) {
        result = TRUE
      }
      else {
        result <- c(result, TRUE)
      }
    }
    else {
      if (start == 1) {
        result = FALSE
      }
      else {
        result <- c(result, FALSE)
      }
    }
    start <- start + 1
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Definitely , Don't use this function !

Comment: Wow! There's a lot of code in that `is.odd` function.  Why is that better than `is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 == 1` ? ... Also, looks like that will be slower since it's growing a vector in a while loop (even though the function already knows the length of the output)

Comment: @GSee you 're right , I saw this mee too I hope I will not dwonvoted for this stupid function :)

Comment: Look at how ugly this is: `suppressMessages(is.odd(c(0, 2, 0, 1, 0)))`.  Wonder why the author doesn't accept that 0 is even. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: @GSee really dirty and ugly:)tha's said , it the school package. The idea maybe to show the algorithm (implements the modulo division)

Comment: +1 for "don't use this function!". It is so ugly it is funny.

Comment: Exactly what an odd function should look like