# Reading Every Other Column in CSV into alternating matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I need to read in a CSV file with no headers and with an unknown number of columns and rows. However , every other column belongs in one matrix while the next needs to be in a different matrix. Example

CSV input:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

Desired result would be equivalent to:

```
matrix1 <- (c( 1, 3,
               1, 3,
               1, 3,
               1, 3), NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns, byrow=T);
```

and

```
matrix2 <- (c( 2, 4,
               2, 4,
               2, 4,
               2, 4), NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns, byrow=T);
```

I have tried something like this (but this seems overly complex and doesn't work anyways). Isn't there a simple way to do this in R?

```
mydata<- read.csv("~/Desktop/file.csv", header=FALSE, nrows=4000);
columnCount<-ncol(mydata);
rowCount<-nrow(mydata);
evenColumns <- matrix(); oddColumns <-matrix();

for (i in 1:columnCount) {
  if (i %% 2) {
    for (l in 1:rowCount){
      col <- 1;
      evenColumns[col, l] <-mydata[i,l];  
      col<-col+1;
    }
  }
  else {
    for (l in 1:rowCount){
      col <-1;
      oddColumns[col, l] <-mydata[i,l];
      col<-col+1;
    }
  }
}
```

How should this be done properly in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the column numbers with `seq`:

```
full = read.csv("mat.csv", header=FALSE)

odds = as.matrix(full[, seq(1, ncol(full), by=2)])
evens = as.matrix(full[, seq(2, ncol(full), by=2)])
```

Output:

```
> odds
     V1 V3
[1,]  1  3
[2,]  1  3
[3,]  1  3
[4,]  1  3
> evens
     V2 V4
[1,]  2  4
[2,]  2  4
[3,]  2  4
[4,]  2  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285004/find-the-indices-of-the-odd-numbers-in-an-integer-vector)

```
mat.even <- mydata[,which(1:ncol(mydata) %% 2 == 0)]
mat.odd <- mydata[,which(1:ncol(mydata) %% 2 == 1)]
```

Comment: Or even `dat[seq_along(dat) %% 2 == 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Every other starting with the first:

```
> cdat[ , c(TRUE,FALSE)]
  V1 V3
1  1  3
2  1  3
3  1  3
4  1  3
```

Every other starting with the second:

```
> cdat[ , !c(TRUE,FALSE)]
  V2 V4
1  2  4
2  2  4
3  2  4
4  2  4
```